# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in Swift 2 call to enumerateTagsInRange

Tags: swift, swift2

I get said error message from the Swift 2 compiler in the line that should call [`enumerateTagsInRange:scheme:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLinguisticTagger/enumerateTagsInRange:scheme:options:usingBlock:). What am I doing wrong?

```
func testTagger() {
    let string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
    let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemesForLanguage("en")
    let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: 0)
    tagger.string = string
    let range = string.characters.indices
    let scheme = NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass
    let options = NSLinguisticTaggerOptions.JoinNames
    tagger.enumerateTagsInRange(range: range, scheme: scheme, options: options) {
                            // ^ error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
        (tag, tokenRange, _,  _) in
        // empty for now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors:

- the first parameter does not have an external name, and
- the first parameter is an `NSRange`, not a Swift `Range`.

Since `NSRange` counts UTF-16 code points, this should work:

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, string.utf16.count)
tagger.enumerateTagsInRange(range, scheme: scheme, options: options) {
    (tag, tokenRange, _,  _) in
    // empty for now
}
```